# Problem in recordsetting of AvAudioRecord in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

Here I am getting the Exception when I am setting the recordsetting in AvAudioRecord.

```
The code I written is as:
```

I created a button named Record and in the action I used the code as...
I imported the audio file sound.caf

```
     [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error: nil];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings; =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

     [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,

     [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,

     [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,

     [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],

     AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];



    AVAudioRecorder *newRecorder =[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: soundFileURL settings: recordSettings error: nil];

    [recordSettings release];

    self.soundRecorder = newRecorder;

    [newRecorder release];
```

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish Calapatapu.

Comment: Actually Im getting Exception at this line

AVAudioRecorder *newRecorder =[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: soundFileURL settings: recordSettings error: nil];

even with ur advice i removed the line
[newRecorder release];
eventhough its generating exception.

Comment: How do you create the soundFileURL?

Comment: by using:

NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory ();
NSString *soundFilePath =[tempDir stringByAppendingString: @"sound.caf"];

Comment: hey Tuomas help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line

```
[newRecorder release];
```